# How to update the control in Loaded handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

The usual routine, progress bar, user clicks the button, process runs, progress bar is updated. Classic.

However I would like to run the process the moment entire app starts, so I run it in `Loaded` handler for `Window` (the only window in my app).

And now, the progress bar is not updated. How to overcome this problem?

Tester for updating progress bar.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    Progress.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(delegate() { ++Progress.Value; }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put all the work on the UI thread, which is used to update the `Progressbar`, so the `Progressbar` is not updated until the work is done. Put the work on a background thread, and update the `Progressbar` from the background thread using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);                    
            Progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() { ++Progress.Value; }), null);
        }
    });
}
```

If you are using .NET 2.0 (not using TPL), you can use `ThreadPool`,

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( (o) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() { ++Progress.Value; }), null);
        }
    });
}
```

Or using `await-async` (.NET 4.5), see, you can call `DoWork()` from any method that marked as `async`.

```
async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await DoWork();
}

async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            await Progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() { ++Progress.Value; }), null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the approach (I got the first edit as well), however the first approach was nice, however I couldn't use it as action passed to another method. This approach however changes synchronous behaviour of the outer loop to asynchronous. And if I call `Wait` I will get to the start point -- no refresh.

Comment: the magic `await-async`, so you are using .NET 4.5; I thought you could be using older versions of .NET so I write the code using the good old `ThreadPool.QUWI`. well, you can use `await-async` to fix your issue, see my update- it is just the new syntax that make us confused.

Comment: Thank you very much! The last approach not only works great (it is synchronous on the outside, can be passed as lambda), but it is very clear to read. Once again, thank you!